# Приложение виснет при больших данных

Tags: c++, qt

Да, допускаю, что сформулировал заголовок глупо..
Дело вот в чём, есть приложение, часть которого занимается поиском директорий и определённых фалйов в этих директориях. Часть кода с поиском директорий проходит успешно и быстро. Часть когда с поиском файлов работает в двух случаях: когда файлов мало, и когда много файлов проходит через отладчик.

То есть я почему и в замешательстве, я в процессе отладки "тыкая" по F5 могу подгрузить более 7 тысяч файлов. А когда абсолютно то же самое без отладки запускаю, висит и всё. При чём висит в самом начале (есть полоса прогресса).

Может сталкивался кто.. Вот код на всякий:

```
double progress_current = 0;
    ui->labelProgressBar->setText("Открытие файлов");

    for (QString &dir : dirList)
    {
        ui->progressBar->setValue((int)((progress_current++ / (double)dirList.size()) * (double)100));

        QDir export_folder(dir);
        export_folder.setNameFilters(QStringList() << "*.jpg" << "*.jpeg" << "*.png");
        QStringList tempFileList = export_folder.entryList();

        for (QString &file : tempFileList)
        {
            Photo temp(dir + '/' + file);
            photoList->push_back(temp);
        }
    }

    ui->progressBar->setValue(100);
    ui->labelProgressBar->setText("Файлы открыты");
```

Вот пруфы на всякий:
1. Во время запуски Realese
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Во время отладки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас загрузка идет в основном потоке, вот гуй и не отвечает.

Короткий способ поправить - добавить в цикл после установки значения в `progressBar` строку

```
QApplication::processEvents();
```

Но это не феншуйно и фу. Правильный способ - выносить длинные задачи в отдельный поток и общаться с основным потоком сигналами.

Comment: Ну если он не будет мне отвечать секунд 5 - и ладно.. То есть в процессе отладки один цикл этот занимает секунд 5. Почему он в релизе (который, как я понимаю, быстрее) работает дольше? Он виснит и не отвечает совсем. Про потоки понятно, да забыл уточнить. Я, само собой их предусмотрю, но сейчас это очень оинтересный вопрос.

Comment: Добавьте прогрессбар и посмотрите, сколько будет выполняться

Comment: В каком смысле? прогрессбар у меня и так добавлен.. или вы имеете ввиду посмотреть точное время?

Comment: процессЭвентс частично помог, спасибо. Но ещё раз, я понимаю как это решить. Я хочу теоритический ответ от знающего, что это за дела и почему так..

Comment: Приведенного вами кода недостаточно, надо разбираться, что вы грузите и как, и нет ли где-то спрятанного неопределенного поведения. Если я правильно понимаю, у вас релизная сборка отрабатывает медленнее, чем дебажная? Это неправильно, проверяйте, точно ли вы работаете с одинаковыми сетами данных, и так далее.